# Remove and replace Pandas DataFrame in Excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am storing a `pandas DataFrame` in an Excel sheet. When I re-run my code, I want the sheet completely overwritten. This is important because my code writes to the same file a few different times, i.e., loading and saving certain sheets at different moments, not wanting to disturb the sheets not currently being changed. Because of this, if a new iteration of the code produces fewer rows or columns, the old data will still be there. For example, if iteration #1 produces 500 rows but iteration #2 only produces 499, that 500th row will still show up in my Excel file.

I'm aware I could loop through all the cells and set their values to `None`, but I thought it would be more efficient to `remove` a given sheet completely, `create_sheet` with the same sheet name, and then save my `DataFrame` to the new sheet. The code below is a MRE of what I'm trying to do. It successfully removes the sheet, creates a new one, and saves the file, but the `to_excel` doesn't seem to be executing. The resulting Excel file has the 'test' sheet, but it is blank.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

df_data = {'A': np.random.randint(1, 50, 20),
            'B': np.random.randint(1, 50, 20),
            'C': np.random.randint(1, 50, 20),
            'D': np.random.randint(1, 50, 20)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)

fn = 'test.xlsx'
sheet = 'test'
df.to_excel(fn, sheet_name=sheet)

df2 = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name=sheet, index_col=0)
df2.drop(columns=['A'], inplace=True)

book = load_workbook(fn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
s = book[sheet]
book.remove(s)
book.create_sheet(sheet, 0)

#THIS CODE WILL ACTUALLY WRITE TO THE SHEET, BUT df2 WILL NOT
#s2 = book[sheet]
#s2['A1'] = 'This will write to the sheet'

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
writer.save()
```

Note that my commented code will write to the proper sheet if uncommented. It seems to just be the `to_excel` line that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using a function:

```
import pandas as pd

def write2excel(filename,sheetname,dataframe):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
        workBook = writer.book
        try:
            workBook.remove(workBook[sheetname])
        except:
            print("There is no such sheet in this file")
        finally:
            dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname,index=False)
            writer.save()
```

After this, assuming you have a datafram `df`, A workbook `Myfile.xlsx` and the sheet you want to overwrite `THE_sheet` do

```
write2excel('Myfile.xlsx','THE_sheet',df)
```

Comment: Well, this works great, but aside from being a OO solution, it seems using `with` is what makes it work properly. Can you explain what using the `with`... `as writer` is doing differently than just saying `writer =` as I did in my code?

Comment: @Tom.to be honest, I am usure. I just use the default use of ```ExelWriter``` as in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html